# Java: How do I do a "onclick" for TextField?

Tags: java, awt

I want to make my text field clear the text when someone clicks it. How can I do this?

Comment: Is this java JTextField?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

on `java.awt.TextField` you can add a `MouseListener` like so

```
TextField field = new TextField();
field.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }

});
```

The reason being that `java.awt.TextField` is a subclass of `java.awt.TextComponent` (which, in turn, is a subclass of `java.awt.Component`). The `Component` class has a `addMouseListener()` method.

Alternatively, you can replace `MouseListener` with `java.awt.event.MouseAdapter` has it encapsulates all of `MouseListener`, `MouseWheelListener` and `MouseMotionListener` methods.

From JavaDoc (of `MouseAdapter`):

> An abstract adapter class for
>   receiving mouse events. The methods in
>   this class are empty. This class
>   exists as convenience for creating
>   listener objects.
>
> Mouse events let you track when a
>   mouse is pressed, released, clicked,
>   moved, dragged, when it enters a
>   component, when it exits and when a
>   mouse wheel is moved.

Comment: Even though I am using only MousePressed, why does eclipse make me have empty functions for all of the others?

Comment: @Doug, because you're implementing an interface and not an abstract class. If you want just `mousePressed`, use `MouseAdapter` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Probably, you need `addMouseListener()`.

**upd**
It would be smt like

```
TextField a = ...;
  a.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
   public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    //some stuff
   }
});
```

upd2
fix keyListener to MouseListener

Comment: Could you possibly type your answers in coherent English?

Comment: @Glenn Nelson, Sorry. I'm trying. It'll be great if you'll tell be about my mistakes.

Comment: @Stas, so it cancelled out...I get it now.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
  TextField.setText("defaultText");

    TextField.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            reSet(evt);
        }
    });

  TextField.addFocusListener(new java.awt.event.FocusAdapter() {
        public void focusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
            reSet(evt);
        }
  });

  void reSet(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
      String temp = jTextField1.getText();
      TextField.setText(temp.equals("defaultText")? "" : temp);
  }
```

Comment: Not sure here: isn't `focusGained(FocusEvent)` fired always when `Component` gets focus, i.e. when you alt+tab to your JFrame?